# JTable: display correctly refresh of a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to display some information on my table and I would like to refresh my table. I am doing it as follows:

```
//rowData and columnname are computed with another piece of code that is working

table = new JTable(rowData, columnName);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
repaint();
```

However, I get the following display (below). I would like to remove grey sqaure which correspond to the table before I update it with the new content in red.

Could anyone please provide me an advice to remove it ?

Thank you for your attention.

Y
[image]

Comment: That isn't just an unpainted rectangle;  it has a border, which means it's an actual JComponent (possibly a JScrollPane).  Since two components cannot exist in the CENTER of a BorderLayout simultaneously, and since your JTable's cells are red, it's clear that you aren't showing all of your relevant code.  Did you alter the layout of the contentPane, perchance?  Did you add a component to the JTable (which you should never do)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add a completely new table. Instead update the data in the data model for your old table.

See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Thanks, it was what I needed ;) !